# Initiating an Express Checkout transaction with python-paypalrestsdk

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

**Issue**

I'm trying to initiate an Express Checkout transaction via server-side python (I'm using Flask).  I'm using the standard [paypal python SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK).

- I'm following the Express Checkout workflow in the documents.
  The PayPal [documentation for Express Checkout](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox) isn't very helpful because it doesn't include any examples for python.
- According to the documents, the first server-side step for an Express Checkout transaction is issuing a `SetExpressCheckout` call to the PayPal API.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to actually do this using the python SDK.

The [examples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/tree/master/samples/payment) in the paypal SDK source code don't seem to have anything relevant to offer.

---

**The question**

How do I initiate a `SetExpressCheckout` call in python to kick off a Paypal Express Checkout workflow?

thanks much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express Checkout API is part of the classic APIs.  The SDK you're showing here is using the REST API, which is a little different, so that's why they're not much help to you.

The [REST API documentation is here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/), and at the top, right you can choose Python for the sample code you'll see.  That documentation should fit more in line with what that SDK is doing for you.

Comment: thanks.  I was aware of the REST vs CLassic API, but was unable to find REST documentation for Express Checkout.  I think Express Checkout may not actually be supported by the REST API today.  If you can confirm this, that answers my question.

Comment: The same functionality is supported, but they just call it "PayPal Payments" instead of Express Checkout from what I can tell.

Comment: I think PayPal Payments is the regular (non-Express) flow.  It sure is confusing.  I just switched to the classic, non-REST API instead and it seems to work fine, although I had to write my own API client. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I've been sticking with as well.  REST is too new and they've tried to rush it to production to compete with Stripe.  Classic is much nicer in my opinion.

Comment: Totally agreed.  If you want to modify your answer to note that REST does not currently support Express Checkout, I'll accept it.  If you're feeling lazy, I will just write it up as a separate answer and accept it....lmk either way.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API does support PayPal Express Checkout. The corresponding actions to `SetExpressCheckout`, `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` and `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` (NVP API) are `create`, `find` and `execute` (REST API).

```
from uuid import uuid4
from paypalrestsdk import Payment, WebProfile
from paypalrestsdk import Api as PaypalAPI

def SetExpressCheckout(client_id, client_secret, data, profile=None, sandbox=False):
    api = PaypalAPI({
            'mode': sandbox and 'sandbox' or 'live',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret})
    if profile:
        profile['name'] = uuid4().hex
        profile['temporary'] = True
        webprofile = WebProfile(profile, api=api)
        if not webprofile.create():
            raise Exception(webprofile.error)
        data['experience_profile_id'] = webprofile.id

    payment = Payment(data, api=api)
    if not payment.create():
        raise Exception(payment.error)
    return payment

payment = SetExpressCheckout(
            client_id='...',
            client_secret='...',
            sandbox=True,
            profile={
                'presentation': {
                    'brand_name': 'My Shop',
                    'logo_image': 'https://www.shop.com/logo.png',
                    'locale_code': 'DE',
                    },
                'input_fields': {
                    'allow_note': False,
                    'no_shipping': 0,
                    'address_override': 0,
                    },
                'flow_config': {
                    'landing_page_type': 'Login',
                    },
                 },
             data={
                 'intent': 'sale',
                 'payer': {
                     'payment_method': 'paypal',
                     'payer_info': {
                         'email': 'buyer@email.com',
                         },
                      },
                  'note_to_payer': 'A note',
                  'redirect_urls': {
                      'return_url': 'https://www.shop.com/success.py',
                      'cancel_url': 'https://www.shop.com/canceled.py',
                      },
                  'transactions': [{
                      'notify_url': 'https://www.shop.com/paypal_notify.py',
                      'item_list': {
                          'items': [{
                              'name': 'Item name',
                              'description': 'Description',
                              'sku': 'SKU',
                              'price': '10.00',
                              'currency': 'EUR',
                              'quantity': 1,
                              }],
                          },
                      'amount': {
                          'total': '10.00',
                          'currency': 'EUR',
                          },
                      'description': 'Description',
                      'payment_options': {
                          'allowed_payment_method': 'INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE',
                          },
                      }],
                  },
             )           

for link in payment.links:
    if link.method == 'REDIRECT':
        redirect_url = link.href
        redirect_url += '&useraction=continue' #'&useraction=commit'
        break
```